# AzureAD authorize writing personal user info

Tags: azure-active-directory

Im learning AzureAd. How do i set up my app so that the user can log in and get read access for all users but only write access to itself? I know this is a very noob question but im finding it difficult to get the right words to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register the app in Azure AD, you would need to setup its required permissions based on your requirements.

As it so happens, there are ones which give it the access you want.
You would need to require access on Microsoft Graph API with the following *delegated permissions*:

[image: Permissions]

You will get R/W access to current user's profile, as well as read access to all users' profiles.
If you need full profiles, use that instead of basic profiles.
But that one requires an administrator to consent the permission.